# Deserialize full JSON to single property for each model in an array using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

When deserializing an array of objects (e.g. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model[]>`), is there a way to have the model's full JSON in one extra property?

For example, if my JSON was:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]
```

and my Model class was:

```
class Model
{
   public string A { get; set; }
   public string B { get; set; }
   public string FullJson { get; set; }
}
```

After deserializing, `FullJson` would contain `{"a":1,"b":2}` for the first model in the array and `{"a":3,"b":4}` for the second.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'd need to make a custom `JsonConverter` for your `Model` class like this:

```
class ModelConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Model);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        Model model = new Model();
        serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), model);
        model.FullJson = jo.ToString(Formatting.None);
        return model;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `Model` class and you should be good to go:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ModelConverter))]
class Model
{
   ...
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hD5WqJ

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.